# REST versus more complicated data requests

Tags: rest

REST APIs work great for get-one, get-a-list etc.

But our frontend has a dashboard, and one part of the dashboard is a more complicated. It requires a query that aggregates/joins several different resources.

Returning the data is not a problem. But what of the taxonomy of the endpoint that returns this data? Since the data is not a resource, what should the URL look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For REST principles it does not matter much if data returned 'aggregates/joins several different resources'. It is implementation detail of underlying data store. The dashboard should not care how exactly that store is implemented, if it uses joins, multiple queries.

Whatever is displayed on dashboard (single item or list of items) still may be treated as resource.

Example: Imagine use case when dashboard shows aggregated user profile from multiple portals (Facebook, Linkedin, etc). You may still have REST resource /user/id for that, even if obtaining that single resource would require many complex operations.

Comment: This is good to know. Can you share, for our hypothetical dashboard item, what POST, PATCH, and DELETE might do? Further, when I pass an ID with GET, what would the ID refer to? The only thing I could think of would be the part of a join necessary for the query to be executed.

Comment: It is hard to give example without domain knowledge. 
Maybe in your case having single dashboard resource does not make sense? maybe dashboard displays a few separate items (each item with separate ID and lifecycle)? in that case you may do better with multiple resources- one per each item. 

For some use cases REST does not fit, for other one need to carefully consider what resource actually is. In this case it may be that dashboard item is not single resource, or not resource at all (because you have problem to find id for each item).

Comment: Indeed, it is a quandry to me.